# Calling getter methods before setter

Tags: java, getter-setter

In any Java program, in general, I will almost always have the getter and setter methods. Calling a setter method before the calling the getter method is the usual rule to follow. However, in theory, one could call the getter method without first calling the setter method. What I am curious about is that can there be any OO designs that could complain at compile time when I mistakenly call the getter method before calling the setter method.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, unless you explicitly threw an exception if the object retrieved by the getter is null.

Comment: "Calling a setter method before the calling the getter method is the usual rule to follow" : Why that ?

Comment: Maybe your getter could return standard uninitialized values instead, properly documented in your Javadoc, like null ?

Comment: Not Yet. You can always initialize an object to its default values using a constructor and then change the values when necessary using a setter. Also `Exceptions` come in handy here.

Comment: If in your case you wanted to safeguard this then you can assign some default values at the time of declaration or use Constructor for that.

Comment: I was looking for "compile time" design principles. Using NULL or throwing exceptions are "run time" --aren't they?

Comment: You want the compiler that is static to correct a dynamic problem of function call order? Humm... you can use final keyword to ensure that a value has been setted once and only once at compilation, but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to check for null in the getter and throw exception if found null.
Thus during runtime if you call a getter without setting its value, it will throw a exception.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Just call your getter method in try catch block, so that even if your getter value is null the flow of execution wont stop.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with a getter method returning null. A problem would only be to try to call methods on an object that points to null.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example

```
 public class Example{

 private String description;
 //Setters and getters
 }


 public static void main(String[] args){
    Example example=new Example();
    if(example.getDescription().length()<=0){    //NullPointerException here
        example.setDescription("Please write some description");
    }
 }
```

So for the Objects you need to check null if you call getter before setter. To avoid this, initialize variables using constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely call a getter before setter but it will return you a null set if the value is not set for the variable.. you can try it with exception handling